# “There was an error completing that action” when clicking 'Enable Crashlytics' on the console page

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics

I have been trying to enable Crashlytics on console for flutter android app, but while clicking the **Enable Crashlytics** button its showing "**There was an error completing that action**".

I was able to successfully configure Crashlytics for iOS app and app is sending crash reports to Crashlytics console from iOS app.

Please help me out in finding out what's wrong as I am not able to get any data on the error. I hae attached screenshots of error for reference. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the browser could be loading a cached version of the console that might have expired credentials, a quick way to  confirm this is by using an incognito window and see if you can reproduce it there too.

Comment: I have tried in incognito mode as well. But the same error is popping up. I am not able to find out what the issue is. No help from Firebase support as well. They have replied they won't be able to provide any help regarding integration. with third party app.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer tools console? I'm wondering if there is a more descriptive error message

Comment: This is the error coming in developer tools console on clicking the Enable Crashlytics button - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 () https://crashlytics-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/397327521756/clients/android:com.sib.mHRMS:onboard?alt=json&key=AIzaSyDovLKo3djdRbs963vqKdbj-geRWyzMTrg. I am unable to understand what this error is. Thanks @Gerardo for your kind help this far.

Comment: hmm i'm also not sure what this error is related to. My suggestion would be to get back to Firebase support and provide as much info as possible like the project ID, package name, the complete 409 error and any other errors you see.